# How to use greater than operator in django template

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue while implementing greater than operator in my template. I have a post in homepage which users can like and I have my friends' profile images displayed beside like count who like the post. Now if 10 friends like my post, i want only five of my friends' profile images to be displayed, and there will be a "+" at the end of displayed images. The "+" signifies that there are more friends who like my post. I tried this but it doesn't work:

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', default="ProfilePicture/user-img.png", blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', related_name="my_friends",blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    poster_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', related_name='image_likes', blank=True)
```

View:

```
def home(request):
    #all post in homepage
    posts = Post.objects.filter(poster_profile=request.user)
    #Show friend who liked Post
    friends_like_img = request.user.profile.friends.all().order_by('-id')
    context = {'posts':posts,'friends_img':friends_img}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}

{% for img in friends_img %}
{% if img in post.likes.all > 20 %}
<img src="{{ img.profile_pic.url }}" height="25" width="25" alt="profile_pic">
{% else %}
<img src="{{ img.profile_pic.url }}" height="25" width="25" alt="profile_pic"> +
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit of a mess, but here are some pointers:

You only ever want five images, so take care of that in the view by [slicing the queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets):

```py
friends_like_img = request.user.profile.friends.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
```

Your template syntax is all off, you could do with reading the docs and getting used to some examples. In the context, you're using `friends_img`, not `friends_like_img` - the context is what the template cares about. Now, since we only ever have five images, we can do this in the template:

```
{% for img in friends_img %}
  <img src="{{ img.profile_pic.url }}" ...>
{% endfor %}
{% if post.likes.count > 5 %}
  +
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @Tom...sorry context name was a typo. But same your code doesn't work. I do not want just the likes count, I want those who are my friends. For example if I have 10 friends, and those 10 friends like my post. I want just 5 of my friends profile_pic to be displayed, that works according to my views, and I also want to have a + at the side of the 5 profile_pic, to signifies that there are more than 5 of my friends who liked my post. If they are less that 5, it will not display a + at the side of my friends profile_pic.

Comment: Can you add your models to the question? Then we can probably filter those in the view. Also, please check your code for typos before posting it.

Comment: @Tom...i have added my model to my question

Comment: I think you'll probably have to rearrange your models for this, perhaps adding a through table for the likes. Then you'll be able to better query it. But this seems like a new question to me, the original question was about the greater than operator, which is not the issue here in any way. You should open a new question with the actual problem, real code without typos, and a better explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Tom...is there no other way I can do this with my code at it is? Or is there a better way I can query for friends who liked my post in views rather than what I have done?

Comment: Possible yes, but not pretty or efficient. The structure isn't the problem (in therms of SQL) but I think in order to get what you need efficiently Django needs an explicit through table so you can use a custom Prefetch object to get the data you need. I could be wrong, of course, but that's what my intuition is telling me.